# Creating Multi Language Blog in Ghost CMS

Tags: content-management-system, ghost-blog

I have been creating a blog in Ghost CMS, where I have to place a dropdown on the header to select the language (English, Chinese, Korean, Japanese).

I have read the possible way to do it, using dynamic routing as in the following URL,

URL: [https://docs.ghost.org/tutorials/multi-language-content/][1]

I have a query that, by using this way do I need to rewrite the content of the blog posts for each languages or not.

Does this method automatically convert the language if I publish the post in english?

Answer (score 2):

There's not automatic language conversion in Ghost. You would need to create separate posts for each language. All dynamic routing gives you is a way to direct URL with a language-specific tag to a particular post.

Comment: wow, as a new user, this is a pretty bad user experience, thanks for sharing, I hope there will be a way to handle multi languages in the admin UI directly

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd let you know that we've updated the tutorial you linked to on using different languages in Ghost: https://ghost.org/tutorials/multi-language-content/

The tutorial shows how to create multi-language content and to use `<link>` elements to add the alternative translations to the meta data. I've created a CodePen demo here on how to create a language select in JavaScript which hooks into those elements: https://codepen.io/daviddarnes/pen/QWwzePz

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to write the content for each blog post and it will be separate by tag.

Example,

```
routes:

collections:
  /:
    permalink: /{slug}/
    template: index
    filter: 'tag:-fr'
  /fr/:
    permalink: /fr/{slug}/
    template: fr
    filter: 'tag:fr'


taxonomies:
  tag: /tag/{slug}/
  author: /author/{slug}/
```